# I trained pix2code, but it always output the same DSL content no matter what image is given

Tags: deep-learning, frontend, lstm, conv-neural-network

When learning pix2code, I found that the trained ***web*** model can only output the same DSL content, that is to say, no matter what pictures are given, the output DSL is the same. Note in advance: since my GPU is only 8g, according to the original configuration of the project, the memory is not enough, so I made some modifications during training, modified dtype (float32 - > float16), the model can be trained, but there are problems as I said above; modified batch_ Size (64 - > 32), after the model is trained, it is also the above problem. What's more, when I have epoch = 10, my loss is always around 0.14. Is this a normal value?

Comment: I'am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Me too , did you find the solution ?